# Keras BatchNormalization population parameters update while training in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, batch-normalization

I am using Keras 2.0.8 with Tensorflow 1.3.0 in Ubuntu 16.04 with Cuda 8.0 and cuDNN 6.

I am using two BatchNormalization layers( **keras layers** ) in my model and training using **tensorflow pipeline**.

I am facing two problems here -

1. BatchNorm layer **population parameters**( mean and variance ) are **not being updated** while training even after setting **K.learning_phase** to **True**. As a result, inference is failing completely. I need some advice on how to update these parameters between training steps manually.
2. Secondly, after **saving the trained model** using tensorflow **saver** op, when I try to **load** it, the **results cannot be reproduced**. It seems the **weights are changing**. Is there a way to keep the weights same in save-load operation?

Comment: I have never heard of similar issues. While training, check if you have set that layer as learnable. Regarding the second issue, weights cannot change after you load the model.

Comment: Setting K.learning_phase() as True, where K is the backend, is supposed to set the layers learnable.
If you are sure that weights remain same, can you please suggest a possible reason why the results cannot be reproduced after loading the model?

Comment: How much change do you observe? If its very small, try setting a random seed. Otherwise, I cannot say. Also, instead of using `K.learning_phase()`, why don't you use the `trainable=True` argument to make the layers learn?

Comment: I am facing the same issue concerning the update of the moving mean and variance in BatchNormalization layers. I've tried a bunch of fixes but none of them worked. Should be concerned as an issue by the keras team.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem a few weeks ago. Internally, keras layers can add additional update operations to a model (e.g. [batchnorm](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/normalization.py#L191)). So you need to run these additional ops explicitly. For the batchnorm these *updates* seem to be just some assign_ops which swap the current mean/variance with the new values. If you do not create a keras model this might work; assuming *x* is a tensor you like to normalize

```
bn = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
x = bn(x)

....
sess.run([minimizer_op,bn.updates],K.learning_phase(): 1)
```

In my workflow, I am creating a keras model (w/o compiling it) and then run the following

```
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=prediction)
sess.run([minimizer_op,model.updates],K.learning_phase(): 1)
```

where *inputs* can be something like

```
inputs = [keras.layers.Input(tensor=input_variables)]
```

and *outputs* is a list of tensorflow tensors. The model seems to aggregate all additional *updates* operations between *inputs* and *outputs* automatically.